# Find last consecutive appearance in cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array that looks like the following:

```
Tickerarray = 

'MNST'    'MNST'    'MNST'    'ALGN'    'ALGN'
'GRA'     'VLO'     'GRA'     'SKS'     'SKS' 
'VLO'     'GRA'     'SKS'     'TSO'     'JDSU'
'TSO'     'TSO'     'TSO'     'VLO'     'TSO'
```

Given a certain column of this cell array, I need to find for each entry the most distant (to the right) consecutive column that contains that entry. For example, given the first column of this cell array, I would want an output:

```
'3'
'3'
'2' % even though VLO appears in column 4, it does not appear consecutively
'5'
```

Given column 3 as input, I would want as output:

```
'1'
'1'
'3'
'3'
```

Comment: I think there's an extra `3` in your example output.  Also, given a column that's not 1, would you want to take into account the columns to the left of it? i.e. given column 3 as input, `SKS` appears consecutively to column 5 - is the desired output `5`?

Comment: You're correct; I edited it. I would not want to take into account columns to the left; I added an example using column 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `strcmp` or similar functions to do the string matching across your cell array, then using `sum` to look for the first column with all zeros (no hits) if any.

```
c= 1; % which column do we want
sArray = Tickerarray(:, c:End); 
l = size(sArray,1); % how many rows

% preallocating output array 
out = ones(l,1).*size(sArray,2); 

for n = 1:l
   str = sArray{n,1};
   x = strcmp(str, sArray); % is logical index of hits
   m = find(sum(x)==0,1); % find first column containing all zeros
   if ~isempty(m)  % else defaults to preallocated value
      out(n) = m-1; 
   end
end
```